# Access Method Objects from Outside of Its Scope?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I create and apply animation to an indefinite number of UIImageView's within my method. Later at some point I need to access UIImageView's to animate them differently or apply some transitions.

I want to find out the best possible way to access them from another method. I thought of using a View Controller's Mutable Array to add them there and later loop through it to retrieve the object I need but I do not know if it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mutable array is not a bad idea at all. You mentioned that you have "an indefinite number of UIImageViews". That sounds that you need a collection to contain them all, how are you doing it right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [self.view subviews] array. You could loop through that and test if the view is a UIImageView. Alternatively, you could set the "tag" property of the views you need to animate when you create them and test for that.